# display data using stored procedure vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview

if i click the search button, i keep on receiving an error at the value of IDNo, incorrect syntax near '11111' can someone help me?

```
    With acc
        IDNo = .IDNo
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse(.StartDate).ToString("M/d/yyyy")
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse(.EndDate).ToString("M/d/yyyy")
        ProjectName = .ProjectName
        ReferenceNo = .ReferenceNo
        TaskCode = .TaskCode
        FileName = .Filename
    End With

    dgAccomplishment.DataSource = Nothing
    dgAccomplishmentPT.DataSource = Nothing
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("dbo.process_time @User='" & IDNo & "' ,@From='" & StartDate & "',@To='" & EndDate & " 11:59:59 PM'", DB.GetConnection)
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgAccomplishment.DataSource = dt
    dgAccomplishment.Columns("ID").Visible = False
    dgAccomplishment.Columns("TimeSave").Visible = False
    da.Dispose()
    dt.Dispose()
```

this is my stored procedure

```
 SELECT a.ID, RTRIM(a.Last_User) [ID No.], 
    RTRIM(Users.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + Users.INITIAL + '. ' + Users.LASTNAME) [Name],
    RTRIM(a.ProjectName) [Project Name], 
    a.ProjectNo, a.ProjectCode, 
    RTRIM(a.Filename) [Filename],
    RTRIM(a.Filesize) [Filesize], 
    RTRIM(a.filesizeunit) [FileSizeUnit],
    a.TimeSave [TimeSave] 
 from DBase.dbo.Acc  a
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users ON a.Last_User = Users.IDNo
 WHERE a.Last_User in (@user) 
    and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),timesave,101) BETWEEN @From AND @To 
 ORDER BY RTRIM(a.SubGroup), RTRIM(a.Last_User)
```

but when i try to run the procedure in a query it works well.

Comment: what is the value that is passed to the @user parameter?

Comment: You need to tell the adapter that you are using a stored procedure to retrieve your records, otherwise it thinks that you are using a SELECT command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using string concatenation, you have the age old single quote problem:  If IDNo value contains a single quote, then your query will fail.

What's worse, your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

You have to escape ALL parameters for single quotes, replacing them by 2 single quotes.

**Best solution here: use parametrized sql**